# XSLT Number in XML TO XML

Tags: xml, date, xslt, transform

Got a little problem with converting of xslt ... 
its a little problem i think but i cant find a solution on the internet. 
when i try to select a number or a date inside a xml node i cannot display in the other xml.
i am using xslt version = 1.0

This is the original code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ALL_Machines_having_buttons_from_a_Machintype_price_greater9700>
   <GreaterTypes>
      <typename>Grant and Sons</typename>
      <price>984912.41</price>
      <serialnumber>7</serialnumber>
      <outputrate>5</outputrate>
      <purchasebillxml>
         <purchasebill>
            <billnumber>345-20-2422</billnumber>
            <seller>
               <id>Nienow-Daugherty</id>
            </seller>
            <product>
               <articlenumber>172185964-0</articlenumber>
               <amount>50359</amount>
               <price>676833.08</price>
            </product>
            <date>2004-01-28</date>
         </purchasebill>
      </purchasebillxml>
      <buttonsname>595027529-2</buttonsname>
      <colour>Khaki</colour>
   </GreaterTypes>
</ALL_Machines_having_buttons_from_a_Machintype_price_greater9700>
```

the XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="/ALL_Machines_having_buttons_from_a_Machintype_price_greater9700">
<humans>
<xsl:for-each select="GreaterTypes">
 <human>
  <firstName><xsl:value-of select="typename"/></firstName>
  <livingyears><xsl:value-of select="amount"/></livingyears>
  <alifesince><xsl:value-of select="date"/></alifesince>
 </human>

</xsl:for-each>

</humans>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

what i get :

```
<humans>
 <human>
  <firstName>Grant and Sons</firstName>
  <livingyears/>
  <alifesince/>
 </human>
</humans>
```

Comment: Your xslt code is not working. You have to remove the first <humans>. Then it works for me as expected.

Comment: you are right i saw the problem ... this is an example i made to demonstrate my problem... somehow in my original file it does not work :( i dont know why

Comment: It is good to simplify the example as far as possible, but that of course means that it still replicates the problem you are interested in. So now you have a simplification that works and you may add in parts of your original until the problem appears again.

Comment: Things to look out for would include whether your element names match between XML and XSLT (Remember, XML and XSLT are case-sensitive). Or maybe the XSLT is looking for elements when they are actually attributes in the XML. Also check if your XML has namespaces (i.e. look for an `xmlns` declaration.)

Comment: down below i posted the original code ... try pls this one . i dont get where the difference is but i does not work

Comment: i edited my question as i was pleased . thanks for the help everybody. maybe u can see my problem now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `date` and `amount` are not direct children of `GreaterTypes` but deeper descendants, so you need to specify the full relative path to them.

For example, for `date` it would be this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="purchasebillxml/purchasebill/date"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/ALL_Machines_having_buttons_from_a_Machintype_price_greater9700">
<humans>
<xsl:for-each select="GreaterTypes">
 <human>
  <firstName><xsl:value-of select="typename"/></firstName>
  <livingyears><xsl:value-of select="purchasebillxml/purchasebill/product/amount"/></livingyears>
  <alifesince><xsl:value-of select="purchasebillxml/purchasebill/date"/></alifesince>
 </human>
</xsl:for-each>
</humans>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional to removing the additional humans-tag, I would also replace the for-each-loop by a template-match. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="/persons">
<humans>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</humans>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="person">
 <human>
  <firstName><xsl:value-of select="name"/></firstName>
  <livingyears><xsl:value-of select="age"/></livingyears>
  <alifesince><xsl:value-of select="birthday"/></alifesince>
 </human>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XSLT looks generally OK.

Remove the first `<humans>`. It is outside of any template
and does not have any matching closing tag.

For the purpose to test your code I removed also
`xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl"`
(not needed).

I tested your code with the above corrections and the result it OK.
Check at http://xsltransform.net/a9Giww

Maybe the real problem is hidden somewhere outside the piece of code that you included in ths post. Look **thoroughly** all your code.